# C types and expressions

Tags: c, types, expression

I had this question on a quiz and I am not sure of the answer:

Given `int *foo(void)`, what are the types of the following expressions? Which of them are lvalues?

```
*foo()  
 &foo()  
 foo()  
 foo  
 &foo
```

This is what I think:

```
 *foo()  type: return int so int?, non-lvalue
 &foo()  type: address of foo(), not sure the type, lvalue (?) because the address has location in memory
 foo()  not sure about this one
 foo    not sure
 &foo   have no clue.
```

I would appreciate to understand the logic behind so if I see similar expression I can understand its type and lvalue.

thanks alot.

Comment: Don't forget that `()` has higher precedence than `*` or `&`, so `*foo()` is a function call and then the `*` dereferences the returned value.

Comment: `foo` decays in most situation to `&foo` so `int* (*)(void)`.

Comment: Presumably you had some kind(s) of material to prepare you for this quiz; you might want to revisit it.

Comment: @malloc `int *foo(void)` returns an `int *`, not an `int`.

Comment: An lvalue is something that can be left of an assignment operator (can be assigned into). As far as I can see, only one of the options is one. (and it's not #2)

Answer (score 1):

- `*foo()` : `int`
- `&foo()` : syntax error
- `foo()`  - `int *`
- `foo` - function type which decays to function pointer in expressions `int *(*)(void)`
- `&foo` - function pointer `int *(*)(void)`